# Memories of previous lives

Tags: science

I think I have to tolerate memories of previous lives. And I know many of which memories are combination of true and false memories.Part of the memories are scientifically superimposed by army or any research department of the government.It is pointless to try to get rid of these memories.Are scientific memories good or bad for me? or are these  cinematic experiments artificial intelligence based?

Comment: If you're asking about implantation of false memories by the government through technological means, I think this is off-topic for Buddhism.SE.

Comment: I have asked the question on "science" tag.The reference of computer,aero-dynamics automatically comes if one wants to elaborate.In our age no one can ignore role of computers in one"s life user 26375

Comment: I think this is a good question. The ability of a Buddhist, particularly a meditating one, to identify memories whether true or false and classify them as good or bad is vital in the path to understanding The Four Noble Truths. Bhaddekaratta ghaatha is a good example of such mental balance.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to remember birth, aging, sickness and death, the suffering again and again. So actually perfect when the proper attention to see the first Noble truth and more perfect then, if having heard the others as well.

Comment: @ Samana johann  iN  BENGALI LANGUAGE THESE ARE CALLED  BITAN[S] .SO AM CITING  THIS BITANS AS HAVE BEEN CREATED BY MILITARY INTELLIGENCE-:ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE USER 26375

Comment: Investigate of what was told, Nyom @ABHIJITBAGCHI . The rest: why, where... real, artificially... is not importand, brings no benefit and would be ever wrong taken.

Comment: since half of the the question was based on  science ,i apologize for if i am not nice but I hoped that  an answer based on science is given.user 26375

Comment: It's all science, but the real one, the one on can see for himself. So why playing around with fake science? Or was anything really till today, @ABHIJITBAGCHI ?

Comment: Does memory change? Is it real? Or not?

Comment: Homesickness,longing for the past,nostalgia.if these are beneficial for one he should put up with that.This depends upon how old is the person.I think my question is not weird,because we can say Military also helped creating the world with the help of artificial intelligence which machines have.Such asElectric lines are not the works of any single individual or country.but my question is if I can not get rid of the memories permanently  created by military by visual computer graphic,cinematic experiments,what is the good of practising yoga or meditation after many years @Samana Johann?

Comment: Again: look at aging, sickness and death with any birth, with any memory, there is nothing to fear that all grasped will break apart but this, and no other phenomena should be seen to let go of what is not real, @ABHIJITBAGCHI . Even more foolish is to hold on what is past. Good actions now, will result in good fruits, so one keeps the focus there and bad things can not arise.

Answer (score 0):

via: http://chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/The_Six_Supernatural_Powers_of_Buddha

PUBBENIVASA - POWER OF KNOWING PREVIOUS EXISTENCES.

The All-knowing One further elucidated thus: "If a monk should frame a wish as follows:- Let me call to my mind many previous states of existence, to wit one birth, two births, three births, four births, five births, ten births, twenty births, thirty births, forty births, fifty births, one hundred births, one thousand births, one hundred thousand births, many destructions of a world cycle (Kappa), many renovations of a world cycle, many destructions and many renovations of a world cycle: I lived in such a place, had such a name was of such a family, of such a caste, had such a maintenance, experienced such happiness and such miseries had such a length of life. Then I passed from that existence and was reborn in such a place. There also I had such a name, was of such a family, of such a caste, had such a maintenance, experienced such happiness and such miseries, had such a length of life. Then I passed from that existence and was reborn in such a place. There also I had such a name, was of such a family, of such a caste, had such a maintenance, experienced such happiness and such miseries, had such a length of life. Then I passed from that existence and was reborn in this existence." Thus let me call to my mind many former states of existence and let me specifically characterise them," then must he be perfect in the precepts etc. -

This power is sorely attributable to the expounding of the "Theory of Rebirth" and 'Samsara' by the Buddha for all living beings in the entire Universe.